# jQuery multiple json requests into an array

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, request

I'm trying to make multiple JSON request inside a loop and save them into a variable so that I can use the variable later. So far I have this, but it returns an empty array. Any helps is much appreciated.

```
function multipleJSON(){
    var arr=[];
    var result = (function () {

        for(var 0=1;i<10;i++){
            .ajax({
                'async': false,
                'global': false,
                'dataType': jsontype,
                'url': 'index.php?param='+i+ '&callback=?',
                'dataType': jsontype,
                'success': function (data) {                 
                    arr.push(data);
                }
            });
        }
        return arr;
    })(); 

    return result;

}

// returns an empty array
my var=multipleJSON();
```

Comment: for(var 0=1;i<10;i++) should be for(var i=1;i<10;i++)

Comment: As @HarryFink, says your for loop is completely wrong. Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-array-in-javascript

Comment: Code is cleaned up and corrected in the for loop. My answer should resolve the main issue.

Comment: @Raidri, you shouldn't not of edited the question to removed the for loop. you've effectivly altered the question. If it was wrong you should of highlighted this in your answer. This edit should of never gotten though the confirm procedure....

Comment: the original code would not run (and return an empty array), so I thought it only a typing error and concentrated on the (in my opinion) main async/callback error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You have an error in you for loop: `for(var 0=1;i<10;i++) {` should be `for(var i=0;i<10;i++) {`
2. You return the `arr` before the ajax calls have finished. You could use a counter in the `success` methods and return the `arr` from the `success` method, when the counter reaches 10.

Comment: -1 for editing the question not adding the code to your answer.

Comment: Thanks for prompt replies and sorry for the typo in the original code. I tried moving the arr in the success method, but it stills does not work. Can you provide me with a complete code? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Since the ajax calls are asynchron, you can't return the array directly, you have to use something like here: http://jsfiddle.net/8yLwy/2/

Answer (score 1):

Try the jquery's when function:

```
$.when(
    $.ajax("/page1.php"), 
    $.ajax("/page2.php")
)
.then(myFunc, myFailure);
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/